# User-global tfignore?

Tags: tfs, tfignore

So TFS supports adding a `.tfignore` file in a repository to exclude files. Does it support a way to add a user-specific or machine-specific global `.tfignore` file?

Git supports this with a`.gitconfig` file and its excludesFile entry.

Here is my situation, why I am asking this. I use WebStorm, but my coworkers do not. So, on my computer, I want to exclude `.idea` folders from TFS checkin without having to modify each repository's `.tfignore` file.

Is there any support for this feature?

Comment: ** If you answer "there is no support" please note the version of TFS in case this feature gets added in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported so far.

You must manually exclude the files in the pengding changes during check in.

Moreover,you can submit your proposal via [Microsoft UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Is there support now, nearly a year and a half later?

Comment: Sorry, it is still on the product teams backlog. For more accurate methods of using `.tfignore`, you could also take a look at this blog [tfignore usage in Team Foundation Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2016/01/29/tfignore-usage-in-team-foundation-server/)